# (Lax, Functional Analysis) Why does he say this space is poor in isometries when there continuum many?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, banach-spaces, intuition, isometry

In chapter 5.3 of the book Functional Analysis by Peter D. Lax, the author says

> It is a fact of life that some Banach spaces are very rich in
> isometries; others are very poor. (...) Among the poor ones are the
> function spaces with the max norm. Here is an example due to Schur:

He immediatly tells us to consider the space of sequences of complex numbers that converge to $0$ with the max norm $||(x_n)|| = max |x_n|$. Then he tells us that for any sequence $(b_n)$ of complex numbers of absolute value $1$ that the operator given by $(Ux)_n = b_n x_n$ is an isometry. And that an operator given by
a permutation of the terms of the sequences is an isometry. He finally says that compositions of these kinds of operators are the only ones.

This is a continuum-sized set of isometries. Why then does the author say that this space is very poor in isometries?

Comment: Perhaps he means that there is not a great variety of kinds of isometries; only compositions of the two kinds described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gold standard for a "rich" collection of isometries is $\ell^2$. One way of quantifying precisely what is meant by "rich" here is, for example, that the isometry group of $\ell^2$ acts transitively on its unit sphere. On the other hand this is very far from true of the isometry group of $\ell^{\infty}$ which has many more orbits acting on its unit sphere.

When it comes to spaces this large just considering the cardinality is not a good way to measure how "rich" the isometry group is.

Comment: Actually I would not be surprised to learn that Hilbert spaces are exactly the Banach spaces whose isometry groups act transitively on their unit spheres. Does anyone know a result along these lines?

Comment: I think this is the "Mazur rotation problem", and is still open.

Comment: @DavidMitra Isn't this problem about separable Banach spaces only? I'm curious if it's also still open for non-separable ones.

Comment: @AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA [This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwivxvWo0OL8AhVwnWoFHYaaDFwQFnoECCEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Frepositorio.usp.br%2Fdirectbitstream%2F5c0f7460-feb5-4a78-863a-b0106b1d28b2%2F3044061.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3ha6xjOC3NAXY5WU8ssdee) states there are counterexamples in the non-separable case.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for any Banach space adding a vector to everything is an isometry, so "continuum of isometries" is not worth much.

Comment: In this context by isometry it was meant isometric automorphism. Therefore I'm pretty sure for every finite dimension there's a Banach space with exactly 2 isometries in this sense. I wonder if this is also true for infinite dimension but maybe thats topic for another question.